# How to stop monit daemon without stop services

Tags: redhat, monit

I'm new on ServerFault.

I'm using monit to start/stop/monitoring services on RHEL7.

Sometime I need to stop the monit daemon (for upgrade it or othen reasons).
But when I stop the monit daemon (systemctl stop monit ; also tried kill -9 ) monit does stop all processes started with him, regardless the monit configuration and regardless the stop script.

Example:

check process apache with pidfile /opt/apache24-p1/logs/httpd.pid
start program  "/opt/apache24-p1/bin/apachectl start"
#stop program  "/opt/apache24-p1/bin/apachectl stop"
#mode passive

monit start apache
then
systemctl stop monit
causes stop httpd daemons without call apachectl

the same uncommenting "mode passive"
also
monit unmonitor all
systemctl stop monit
causes stop httpd

also

monit start apache
rm /etc/monit.d/apache
monit reload
systemctl stop monit
causes stop httpd

note that parent pid of httpd is not monit.

There is a way to stop monit without stop the service?

Thankyou.

Comment: Please check your main process and dependency of them with pstree command . If you have dependency on them . No way they call each other and if you stop one process another cannot work

Comment: Why do you use monit? It's mostly redundant now.

Comment: There are not dependecies. httpd is a child of systemd. strace show that the httpd process receive a sigterm&&sigchld&&sigcont from systemd. I found the httpd pid in /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice/monit.service/cgroup.procs